# Move constructor and pre-increment vs post-increment

Tags: c++, constructor, move

In C++, if you have a for loop that *"copies"* objects of a user defined type using a move constructor, does it make any difference if you use `++i` or `i++` as the loop counter?

I know this question seems rather vague, but I was (I believe) asked this in a phone interview. I wasn't sure if I understood the question correctly, and the interviewer took this as my not knowing the answer, and cut the interview short.

What could he have been getting at?

Comment: Also see Herb Sutter's [GotW #2 Solution: Temporary Objects](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/13/gotw-2-solution-temporary-objects/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In C++, if you have a for loop that "copies" objects of a user defined type using a move constructor [...]

First of all, a move constructor is used for move-constructing, which usually means you are not "copying": you *can* realize moving as copying - in fact, a class which is copy-constructible is also move-constructible - but then why defining a move constructor explicitly?

> [...] does it make any difference if you use ++i or i++ as the loop counter?

It depends on what `i` is. If it is a scalar object, like an `int`, then there is no difference at all.

If `i` is a class-type iterator, on the other hand, `++i` should be more efficient (on a purely theoretical ground), because the implementation of `operator ++` will not have to create a copy of the iterator to be returned before the iterator itself is incremented.

Here, for instance, is how stdlibc++ defines the increment operators for the iterator type of an `std::list`:

```
_Self&
operator++()
{
    _M_node = _M_node->_M_next;
    return *this;
}

_Self
operator++(int)
{
    _Self __tmp = *this;
    _M_node = _M_node->_M_next;
    return __tmp;
}
```

As you can see, the postfix version (the one accepting a dummy `int`) has more work to do: it needs to create a copy of the original iterator to be refurned, then alter the iterator's internal pointer, then return the copy.

On the other hand, the prefix version just has to alter the internal pointer and return (a reference to) itself.

However, please keep in mind that when performance is concerned, all assumptions have to be backed up by measurement. In this case, I do not expect any sensible difference between these two functions.

Comment: Got it on the "copying" part. I knew I shouldn't have used that word. So this has nothing to do with move construction per se, right? It has to do with ints vs iterators?

Comment: @Scott: Indeed, that's the case. I am going to expand the answer with an example

Comment: @Scott: while I think Andy nailed a case where it matters, for what it's worth I think the question (if you phrased it correctly) was piss-poor.

Comment: @Koushik: Hard to tell whether something is "dangerous" without knowing what is actually in the loop, and what is being moved from, and whether an attempt is made to invoke a function with preconditions on the state of the thing that has been moved from... If the rhs is an lvalue, this means the programmer wrote `std::move(obj)`, and one should trust that they are not going to do inappropriate stuff with `obj` later on...

Comment: @Nik. Agreed. I hesitated before asking because for the life of me I couldn't figure out why the interviewer was talking about move construction and pre/post increment in the same question. Still have no idea...

Comment: @NikBougalis: Agreed, unless something else was meant by the interviewer when mentioning that move constructor. But without actually describing what's going on in the loop, I had to assume the question was about the efficiency of `i++` vs `++i`

Comment: @Scott: I know that when you're being interviewed, it's hard to speak up. But as someone who sits on the *other* side of the table, let me give you two hints: if I ask you a question you don't understand, you should ask for clarification, and if you think the question is nonsensical you should say so *politely* and explain why. You are being evaluated for a job that requires you to exercise your critical thinking and will challenge your analytical abilities. Don't shut down those parts of your brain during the evaluation.

Comment: @AndyProwl Have you actually measured the difference between `++i` and `i++` for an iterator?  I once did, for all of the iterators on standard library components (including the reverse iterators).  There is _no_ difference in performance---at least not any that could be measured.  Peoply who recommand one over the other on performance grounds are simply doing speculative premature optimization.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Agreed, that's what I would expect. I hope my answer did not sound like any such recommendation.

Comment: @JamesKanze Sutter & Alexandrescu (C++ Coding Standards, Item 9) call preferring pre-increments over post-increments "avoiding premature pessimization". Not quite the same as premature optimization.

Comment: @rhalbersma I don't know why they get in such a dither over something so unimportant.  On a new, green fields project, I'd say to prefer pre-incrementation just to avoid long and fruitless discussions about the performance impact (which is 0).  On an existing project, I'd go with whatever is already being done, since there's no real technical argument against it.

Comment: @JamesKanze perhaps because they also recommend to use checked iterators (Item 83)?